# How to get the last process which changed a file in Unix?

Tags: unix

I need to know a way by which I can get which process changed a particular file the last time. Any tools or shell commands for the same would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to setup a logging/auditing so you can get this data in the future, or are you trying to find the cause of an existing change.  If it is the later, then I suspect you are out of luck.

Comment: I am trying to find the cause of an existing change, but the change will replicate itself once I remove the file. Its related to this issue http://serverfault.com/questions/365509/how-to-resolve-apache2-2-htaccess-vulnerability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html